# Conways Game of Life with more rules

Tags: javascript, canvas, conways-game-of-life

I'm working on Conway's game of life with 2 more rules.
First rule is we have 10% to born good cell with green color in our grid which can born all cells around from it, and we have same percent to born bad cell with red color which destroy all cells around it. I can't understand how to realize that.
Does anyone have an idea on how to do that?

Cells creating by drawing with mouse:

```
var livingCells = me.cells.filter(function(c){
        return c.isAlive;
    }).forEach(function(c){
        ctx.fillStyle = me.cellColor;
        ctx.fillRect(c.x * width, c.y * height, width, height);

    });
```

Then I'm detecting neighbors and checking what cell will die or remain alive:

```
me.getNeighbors = function(){

    return [grid.getCell(x-1, y-1),
            grid.getCell(x-1, y),
            grid.getCell(x-1, y+1),
            grid.getCell(x, y-1),
            grid.getCell(x, y+1),
            grid.getCell(x+1, y-1),
            grid.getCell(x+1, y),
            grid.getCell(x+1, y+1)];

}
me.shouldDie = function(){
    var livingNeighbors = me.getNeighbors().filter(function(c){
        return c.isAlive;
    });


    if(livingNeighbors.length < 2){
        return true;
    }

    if(livingNeighbors.length > 3){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


me.shouldBeBorn = function(){
    var livingNeighbors = me.getNeighbors().filter(function(c){
        return c.isAlive;
    });

    if(livingNeighbors.length === 3){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[My solution with original rules](http://www.filedropper.com/gameoflife2)

Comment: in English please ? :)

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck, sorry for my English, what you dont understad? Maybe I can explain more detailed.

Comment: I have to admit I don't know what you mean by "to born". Also, we have 10% *what*?

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck, "to born" I mean the programm has 10 percent chance to create good or bad cell in grid.

Comment: sorry, still don't get it. You should add details to your question.

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck, ok, You know what is Conway's game of life? Or I need more details about this?

Comment: I also suggest you put your current code on a jsFiddle or Plunkr.

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck, ok, I realize all original rules from this game, but still need 2 more rules. 1) Random with 10 percent chance in field creates  "bad" or "good" cell  from "dead" or "alive" cell with other color  then other cells (dead cells - gray and alive cells - blue). Then if randomly creates bad cell, all alive cell around from it will be dead, in other way if randomly creates good cell, all dead cells around will be alive.

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck: No, please suggest to put the code in the question. Or at least the relevant excerpts of it that are responsible for creating cells and propagation. A fiddle including an interactive display output would be a nice addition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got a version working with the original rules, your design includes an intermediary buffer to store alive/dead values while the field is still being analyzed.

In order to implement new rules, you would need another buffer.

As in:

```
field = Conway_field()

while True:
    buffer1 = apply_rule_1(field)
    buffer2 = apply_rule_2(buffer1)
    field = buffer2
```

So, if I understand your question, you need to calculate the next generation based on the regular rules, then calculate another generation based on your new rules.  Also, it soulds like the new rule you want to implement may take two steps, like so:

```
field = Conway_field()

while True:
    buffer1 = regular_rules(field)
    buffer2 = add_random_red_or_green_cells(buffer1)
    buffer3 = kill_red_neighbors_birth_green_neighbors(buffer2)
    field = buffer3
```

I know you're not using python, but I think it's illustrative of a point.  Hope this helps!